# Printing DB variables in different columns

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to print variables in Python from a DB so that they print with one variable in its own column. I have the following:

```
import os,MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(read_default_file="/etc/my.cnf",read_default_group="mysql",db="Cinderella")

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "select * from DatasetStatus"

try:
    print '\n Mysql> ' + sql
    cursor.execute(sql)

    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        name = row[0]
        nused = row[1]
        ndownloads = row[2]
        incache = row[3]
        entrydate = row[4]
        size = row[5]

            print "%n|%u|%d|%c|%e|%s"%\
             (name|nused|ndownloads|incache|entrydate|size)
except:
    print " Error ($s): unable to fetch data."%(sql)

db.close()
```

Those six lists of values that are stored in different rows are the values that I want to print in columns. Any suggestions as to how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You could just do `print '{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}'.format(*row)` and not bother manually unpacking `row` if you only need to print with it.

Example:

```
>>> row = ('hello', 'world', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test')
>>> print '{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}'.format(*row)
hello|world|this|is|a|test
```

You would amend yours as such:

```
try:
    print '\n Mysql> ' + sql
    cursor.execute(sql)

    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        print '{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}'.format(*row)

except:
    print "Error ($s): unable to fetch data." % (sql)
```

Comment: I tried doing that and it says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` with an arrow pointing at the "p" in print.

Comment: I amended my answer to more clearly explain how your code would change.

Comment: It now gives the following error: `Mysql> select * from DatasetStatus`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "snapshotSmartCacheDb.py", line 27, in ?`
    `print " Error ($s): unable to fetch data."%(sql)`
`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: Change `'($s)'` to `'(%s)'`.  Also, using such a broad exception handler can lead to unintended results.  I would remove the entire try/except bit and see why it's failing.  That print statement should work fine, unless `row` has more/fewer than 6 items.